# What is the correct way to validate all form fields on submit when using ng-repeat for dynamic form?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-validation

I have a form with some fields (build with ng-repeat, so I dont know how much). I added to the submit button

```
ng-disabled=form.field.$invalid
```

and added to all the fields "required" but the ng-disabled work just for this last field. my code:

```
 <form name="form" novalidate>

            <div ng-repeat="q in questions">
                 <textarea name="answer" type="text"  ng-model="answers[$index]" required></textarea>


            </div>
            <button ng-disabled="form.answer.$invalid || form.answer.$pristine" type="submit" ng-click="submit(q)">'Submit'</button>
        </form>
```

how can I validate the user change all fields? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because all your inputs have the same name, hence the behavior due to the form controller instance will have just one property with the name `answers` and it will point to the last ng-model with that name in the form. Instead provide different names for your inputs using `ng-attr-name` with probably appending `$index` and use `$invalid` property of the form, form will be invalid as long as one of the ng-model(s) (with constraints) within the form is invalid. So just disable the button until the form is invalid since it is a catch-all property on the form controller.

```
<div ng-repeat="q in questions">
  <!-- Provide dynamic form names -->
  <textarea ng-attr-name="answer{{$index}}" type="text" 
            ng-model="answers[$index]" required></textarea>
 </div>
 <!-- Use form.$invalid -->
 <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid || form.$pristine"  
         type="submit" ng-click="submit(q)">Submit</button>
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.questions = ["q1", "q2"]
  $scope.answers = {};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <form name="form" novalidate>

    <div ng-repeat="q in questions">
      <textarea ng-attr-name="answer{{$index}}" type="text" ng-model="answers[$index]" required></textarea>


    </div>
    <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid || form.$pristine" type="submit" ng-click="submit(q)">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```